# Matlab Pso Algorithm

Tags: matlab, optimization, symbolic-math, particle-swarm

I'm trying to solve a symbolic optimization problem using PSO optimizer in MATLAB. The variables r x a c n theta z are symbolic and CD is calculated by integrating r.
The CD is the objective function with free variables a,n, theta and lb and ub are bounds. Full code is as follows:

```
    syms r x a c n theta z
    assume(n,'positive');
    D=0.24; 
    L=2;   
    f=L/D;  
    b=.8;   
    a0=0.02; 
    db=0.05;  
    V=1;    
    Re=(V*(D/2))/0.000001; 
    Cf=(0.075/(((log10(Re))-2)^2))+0.00025;
    
    % Define r(x) 
    c=L-a-b-a0;

    r1=0.5*D*(2*x/a)^(1/n);
    I1=simplify(int(2*pi*r1,x,a0,a));
    r2=D/2;
    I2=simplify(int(2*pi*r2,x,a,a+b));
    r3=(0.5*D)-((((3*D)/(2*(c)^2))-(tan(theta)/c))*(x-a-b)^2)+(((D/c^3 ... 
    (tand(theta)/c^2))*(x-a-b)^3); 
    I3=simplify(int(2*pi*r3,x,a+b,L));
    A=simplify(I1+I2+I3);
    Sn=pi*(D^2/4);
    Cdstar=Cf*(1+(60*f^-3 )+(0.0025*f))*(A/(L^2));
    Cdb=0.029*((db/D)^3)*(Cdstar^-0.5)*(Sn/(L^2));
    CD=simplify(Cdstar+Cdb);

    %optimization problem

    objective=matlabFunction(CD,'Vars',[a,n,theta])
    nVar=3;
    
    lb = [deg2rad(5),0.25,a0];
    ub = [deg2rad(60),5,L/2];


    options = 
    optimoptions('particleswarm','SwarmSize',100,'HybridFcn',@fmincon);

    [z,fval,exitflag,output] = particleswarm(objective,nVar,lb,ub,options)
```

And this is the error I get:

> @(a,n,theta)pi.*4.404634153141517e-4+pi.*1.0./sqrt(pi.*4.404634153141517e-4-pi.*(a.*5.0-6.0).*1.0./(a.*5.0e+1-5.9e+1).^3.*(a.*2.32335e+6+tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*4.779e+6-tan(theta).*6.2658e+6-a.^2.*tan(theta).*2.655125e+7+a.^3.*tan(theta).*1.4875e+7-a.^4.*tan(theta).*3.125e+6-a.*tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*1.59975e+7+a.*tan(theta).*2.1063e+7+a.^2.*tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*2.008125e+7-a.^3.*tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*1.1203125e+7+a.^4.*tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*2.34375e+6-a.^2.*1.98e+6+a.^3.*5.625e+5-9.08811e+5).*1.223509486983755e-5-(n.*pi.*((a.*2.5e+1).^(-1.0./n)-2.0.^(1.0./n+1.0).*a.*2.5e+1).*1.101158538285379e-5)./(n+1.0)).*9.440104166666668e-7-pi.*(a.*5.0-6.0).*1.0./(a.*5.0e+1-5.9e+1).^3.*(a.*2.32335e+6+tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*4.779e+6-tan(theta).*6.2658e+6-a.^2.*tan(theta).*2.655125e+7+a.^3.*tan(theta).*1.4875e+7-a.^4.*tan(theta).*3.125e+6-a.*tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*1.59975e+7+a.*tan(theta).*2.1063e+7+a.^2.*tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*2.008125e+7-a.^3.*tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*1.1203125e+7+a.^4.*tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*2.34375e+6-a.^2.*1.98e+6+a.^3.*5.625e+5-9.08811e+5).*1.223509486983755e-5-(n.*pi.*((a.*2.5e+1).^(-1.0./n)-2.0.^(1.0./n+1.0).*a.*2.5e+1).*1.101158538285379e-5)./(n+1.0)
>
> Not enough input arguments.
>
> Error in
> symengine>@(a,n,theta)pi.*4.404634153141517e-4+pi.*1.0./sqrt(pi.*4.404634153141517e-4-pi.*(a.*5.0-6.0).*1.0./(a.*5.0e+1-5.9e+1).^3.*(a.*2.32335e+6+tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*4.779e+6-tan(theta).*6.2658e+6-a.^2.*tan(theta).*2.655125e+7+a.^3.*tan(theta).*1.4875e+7-a.^4.*tan(theta).*3.125e+6-a.*tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*1.59975e+7+a.*tan(theta).*2.1063e+7+a.^2.*tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*2.008125e+7-a.^3.*tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*1.1203125e+7+a.^4.*tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*2.34375e+6-a.^2.*1.98e+6+a.^3.*5.625e+5-9.08811e+5).*1.223509486983755e-5-(n.*pi.*((a.*2.5e+1).^(-1.0./n)-2.0.^(1.0./n+1.0).*a.*2.5e+1).*1.101158538285379e-5)./(n+1.0)).*9.440104166666668e-7-pi.*(a.*5.0-6.0).*1.0./(a.*5.0e+1-5.9e+1).^3.*(a.*2.32335e+6+tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*4.779e+6-tan(theta).*6.2658e+6-a.^2.*tan(theta).*2.655125e+7+a.^3.*tan(theta).*1.4875e+7-a.^4.*tan(theta).*3.125e+6-a.*tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*1.59975e+7+a.*tan(theta).*2.1063e+7+a.^2.*tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*2.008125e+7-a.^3.*tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*1.1203125e+7+a.^4.*tan((theta.*pi)./1.8e+2).*2.34375e+6-a.^2.*1.98e+6+a.^3.*5.625e+5-9.08811e+5).*1.223509486983755e-5-(n.*pi.*((a.*2.5e+1).^(-1.0./n)-2.0.^(1.0./n+1.0).*a.*2.5e+1).*1.101158538285379e-5)./(n+1.0)
>
> Error in particleswarm>makeState (line 694)
> firstFval = objFcn(state.Positions(1,:));
>
> Error in particleswarm>pswcore (line 169) state =
> makeState(nvars,lbMatrix,ubMatrix,objFcn,options);
>
> Error in particleswarm (line 151) [x,fval,exitFlag,output] =
> pswcore(objFcn,nvars,lbRow,ubRow,output,options);
>
> Error in MYRING_SYMS_optimisation_K (line 56) [z,fval,exitflag,output]
> = particleswarm(objective,nVar,lb,ub,options)
>
> Caused by:
> Failure in initial objective function evaluation. PARTICLESWARM cannot continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fun` takes only one argument, which is a vector with `nvars` elements. From `particleswarm` [doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/particleswarm.html):

> `x = particleswarm(fun,nvars)` attempts to find a vector x that achieves a local minimum of `fun`. `nvars` is the **dimension** (number of design variables) of `fun`.

So you need to declare a new objective function that only takes 1 argument:

```
[z,fval,exitflag,output] = particleswarm( ...
    @(x) objective(x(1), x(2), x(3)), ...
    nVar,lb,ub,options)
```